# How can I store a returned List<T> in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

This should be simple, but I keep running into problems with this. I have a generic class `Csvs<T>`with a method that returns a type `List<T>` through a Property called `Dockets`. (The method reads CSV files and returns the list of the records in that CSV file. T is the type of that CSV file, which is defined in a series of models, which contain the header row as Properties)

In my calling class (which I *cannot* make generic), I have a switch statement based on an `enum` that contains the names of the classes I use in T.

```
switch (_userInput.CsvType)
            {
                case CsvType.Type1:
                    var csvType1 = new Csvs<Type1>(_userInput);
                    _dockets  = csvType1.Dockets;                        
                    break;
                case CsvType.Type2:
                    var csvType2 = new Csvs<Type2>(_userInput);
                    _dockets  = csvType2.Dockets;                        
                    break;
                case CsvType.Type3:
                    var csvType3 = new Csvs<Type3>(_userInput);
                    _dockets  = csvType3.Dockets;                        
                    break;
                // more cases here [...]
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
```

(It would be nice if I could find a better way than using this switch, too, but it works for now.)

What does not work, or what I do not know how to do is, how to declare `_dockets`? Since T could be any of the types. I've tried extracting an interface `ICsvs` and have the class inherit it, and then declare

```
var _dockets = new List<ICsvs>;
```

But this throws an error, that I can't implicitly convert the `List<Type1>` to a `List<ICsvs>`.

And I can't cast the List to a type `List<ICsvs>`. (Then I get the next exception)

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

The same happens if I use an abstract class.

So, how do I store the returned List in the calling class? How do I declare a field or property that can hold any of the types?

Comment: Generics always work best when you know the type at compiletime. If you only know they type at runtime, you *probably* dont want generics.

Comment: @Jamiec, The generic class works... I just don't know how to store the return type?

Comment: Exactly my point. You can use a switch to instantiate the right generic class, but you cant consume it in any meaningful way as you dont know they type.

Comment: you can't store cause you don't iknow the type beforehand. You are left with using another switch probably or using `dynamic`

Comment: @Rahul. Thank you! I forgot about `dynamic`. That will work!

Comment: Why can't you just use `_dockets.AddRange(csvType1.Dockets)`? If `dockets` is `List<ICsvs>` and `csvType1.Dockets` is a list of instances of some type that implements `ICsvs`, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Youve accepted an answer which *does not work* which will further confuse the next visitor to SO with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for what I was after, that is, storing the return value for later use, `dynamic` is the best answer (Thank you @Rahul). I can worry about the type later. Thank you all for your help.

```
dynamic _dockets;
```

then switch-case through the returns.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to make all of your types implementing ICsv, like this:

```
interface ICsv { }

class CsvType1 : ICsv { }

class CsvType2 : ICsv { }

class Csvs<TCsvModel> 
   where TCsvModel: ICsv
{
    public Csvs(IList<TCsvModel> csvModel)
    {
       this.Dockets = csvModel;
    }

    public IList<TCsvModel> Dockets { get; private set;}
}
```

So you can use this like:

```
IEnumerable<ICvs> dockets;

var cvsType1 = new Csvs<CsvType1>(_input);
dockets = cvsType1.Dockets

var cvsType2 = new Csvs<CsvType2>(_input);
dockets = cvsType2.Dockets
```

Comment: That's nice. Thank you.

Comment: This will not work for the same reason as the OP's code did not work. http://rextester.com/PRWX41261

Comment: No, close: It throws `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CsvTypes.ICsvs>'`

Comment: what's the type of _userInput ?

Comment: @vdefeo It's a custom class that has the type of csv and a few Properties, such as the date and time when the csv was written, etc

Comment: Ok you're right IList doesn't fit the return type, I've just changed to IEnumerable, I would prefer to work with IEnumerable instead of dynamics only because performance issues, dynamic will resolve the type in runtime and it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

The most meaningful/polymorphic thing you can do is make the `Dockets` property return an interface describing what you do with them. Depending on your requirements, that may or may not be feasible - but you have little other option. As I commented, Generics really only works well when you know the type at compile-time.

By way of an example. An interface

```
public interface IDockets
{
    void DoSomethingWithRecords();
}
```

A generic implementation which will be returned from your `Csvs` class

```
public class Dockets<T> : IDockets
{
    private IEnumerable<T> dockets;
    public Dockets(IEnumerable<T> dockets)
    {
      this.dockets = dockets;
    }
    public void DoSomethingWithRecords()
    {
        foreach(var docket in dockets)
             Console.WriteLine(docket); // do whatever
    }
}
```

This class would then be returned from your `Csvs` class `Dockets` property

```
public class Csvs<T>
{
    private List<T> parsedDockets; // assume you have something like this:
    public IDockets Dockets{ get { return new Dockets(parsedDockets); } }
}
```

And your calling code

```
IDockets dockets = null;
switch (_userInput.CsvType)
{
    case CsvType.Type1:
        var csvType1 = new Csvs<Type1>(_userInput);
        dockets  = csvType1.Dockets;                        
        break;
   // Snip //
}
dockets.DoSomethingWithRecords();
```

Comment: The problem with the IEnumerable is that I need to add the values from the CSV, so a List would work much better.

Comment: @ToshiBoy whatever, List or enumerable makes no difference. Anyway, you're presumably adding them to a list in `Csvs` - by the time you spit them out to `Dockets` you probably dont need to add any more.